# Vaadin - How to convert a Grid column which has boolean value to Checkbox

Tags: checkbox, vaadin

I am using Vaadin 7.6.4 for my UI work. This has the following:-

- I have a window which contains a grid with data in it. This window is actually a kind of a pop up[ which shows up when my main screen gets a click on the settings icon( not shown here). This is working fine( getting the UI screen to open the Vaadin window when the settings icon the main screen is clicked).
- The problem is in showing the data as mentioned below.
- This grid will have 4 columns for which the data comes from a bean container.
- The first column is a boolean field with true/false getting displayed based on the data from the bean container.
- I need to convert this boolean field column into a checkbox with true showing the field as a checkbox with a value selected. If the value is false, then show a checkbox which is not selected.
- I am trying to do that as shown in the code below but I keep getting this checkbox name printed. I dont see the checkbox but the word "checkbox" printed in there?
- This checkbox should be editable. The idea is that the user should be able to select some checkboxes and the ones selected should be shown in a panel ( not shown here). Thus, the checkbox has to be editable.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The `CheckboxRenderer` from the [grid-renderers-collection-for-vaadin7](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/grid-renderers-collection-for-vaadin7) seems to do what you want, although in my tests it had a weird behaviour when editing. Perhaps you can get some inspiration from the [sources](https://github.com/vaadin/grid-renderers-collection-addon) and create your own renderer which behaves just like you want. As an alternative you can take a look at [the component renderer](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/componentrenderer) addon which decorates the grid with renderers for components.

Comment: thanks for the help. However, we ended up using the SelectionMode.MULTI option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we used the SelectionMode.MULTI to show the selection of rows in there. 
https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/latest/vaadin-grid/demo/selection.html

Still, I would love to learn more as to how we get the change done as shown in the question above.

Still looking for an answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Renderer and a Converter, you don't need to use `SelectionMode.MULTI`.

An example of this is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40707956/5550041).